# 404 Not found Laravel8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I used to code with this framework in the oldest versions but now it been difficult for me to understand its documentation regarding routes and links in the blade so I need some help.

These are my routes `web.php`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PeliculaController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/pelicula', [PeliculaController::class, 'index'])->name('pelicula');
Route::get('/detalle', [PeliculaController::class, 'detalle'])->name('pelicula.detalle');
```

This is my `PeliculaController` with my methods:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PeliculaController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $titulo = 'Listado de mis peliculas';
        return view('pelicula.index', [
            'titulo' => $titulo
        ]);
    }

    public function detalle() {
        return view('pelicula.detalle');
        die();
    }
}
```

**detalle.blade.php:**

```
<a href="{‌{ route('pelicula') }}">Ir al listado</a>
```

**index.blade.php:**

```
<a href="{‌{ route('detalle.pelicula') }}">Ir al detalle</a>
```

The issue is the following when I run my project and click on the hyperlink of detalle.blade.php the page is not found. I couldn´t shorten more my code due that I want to understand what I'm doing wrong because one link works and the other doesn´t it just shows de 404 Not Found error.

Answer (score 2):

Your route should be `pelicula.detalle`, not `detalle.pelicula`. You named it that way.

```html
<a href="{‌{ route('pelicula.detalle') }}">Ir al detalle</a>
```

Comment: okey the thing is that when i want to use the link that takes me to the link of the route using the index method, so i never been to reach the point on using the other link. So i open localhost:8000/detalle, and when i click on <a href="{‌{ route('pelicula') }}">Ir al listado</a> i have the issue 404 not found.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you are saying

Comment: My bad, my point is i want to access the route: 
Route::get('pelicula/{pagina?}', [PeliculaController::class, 'index'])->name('pelicula'); Using: 
<a href="{‌{ route('pelicula') }}">Ir al listado</a>
But the when i run the project and click on the link it takes me to 404 not found.

Comment: Please update your question, and attach your routes.php

Answer (score 0):

First, you have called the wrong route name, try to use the below code:

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/detalle', [PeliculaController::class, 'detalle'])->name('pelicula.detalle');
```

Your blade file:

`index.blade.php`

```
<a href="{‌{ route('pelicula.detalle') }}">Ir al detalle</a>
```

If your problem is not solved, try to remove your route-cache using the below command:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

**Note:** This command removes your route caches.